# I cannot modify NavigationController, is there anything wrong in my code?

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyDrop
import Material

class HomePageView: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = Color.blue.base
        self.navigationItem.title = "test"
        self.navigationItem.titleLabel.textColor = .black
        self.navigationItem.detail = "Build an app"
    }

    func pushSelf () {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondPageView(), animated: true)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        preparePageTabBarItem()
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        preparePageTabBarItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}

extension HomePageView {
    fileprivate func preparePageTabBarItem() {
        pageTabBarItem.title = "Blue"
        pageTabBarItem.titleColor = Color.blueGrey.base

    }
}
```

I use these code in my ViewController to modify the NavigationController, but it keeps blank and doesn't change at all, I cannot use Material that skillfully, so I wonder if you could give me some advice.
[image]

Comment: Use    self.title = "test"

Comment: Add the screen shot of storyboard with your HomePageView controller.

Comment: I didn't use storyboard, I prefer using code.

Comment: Can you share you code setup for `NavigationController`? Thank you!

Comment: Can you check if your self.navigationController? is not nil? use this code in your viewDidLoad `if self.navigationController != nil { debugPrint("is not nil")}else{debugPrint("is nil")}` and share what show the console log

Comment: Post the code how you embed HomePageView in the navigation controller. for showing the details on navigation controller it needs to be embedded in NavigationController(From material framework).

Comment: Can you show the code for your `NavigationController` and `PageTabBarController` setup? Thank you!